# I need to display an Arabic date picker

Tags: flutter, dart, datepicker, flutter-getx

I need to display an Arabic date picker , I can't control this with Locale constructor .
It's only display an English view .

> Pick date metod

```
  DateTime selectedDate = DateTime.now();

  Future<void> _selectDate(BuildContext context) async {
    final DateTime picked = await showDatePicker(
        context: context,
        initialDate: selectedDate,
        firstDate: DateTime(2000, 1),
        lastDate: DateTime(2100),
        builder: (BuildContext context, Widget child) {
          return Theme(
            data: Theme.of(context).copyWith(
                colorScheme: ColorScheme.light(primary: primaryColor)),
            child: child,
          );
        });

    if (picked != null && picked != selectedDate) {
      selectedDate = picked;
    }
  }
```

> Main Screen

```
void main() async {
      WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
      await GetStorage.init();
      runApp(
        MyApp(),
      );
    }

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GetMaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      translations: Translation(),
      locale: Locale(AuthController().appLocal.value),
      fallbackLocale: Locale(AuthController().appLocal.value),
      title: 'Hesabate App',
      theme: ThemeData(
        canvasColor: Colors.transparent,
        fontFamily: "NotoNaskhArabic_font",
      ),
      initialRoute: AppRoutes.splashScreen,
      getPages: AppRoutes.routes,
    );
  }
}
```

> I have an updated language(en&ar) at this variable

```
AuthController().appLocal.value
```

[image: An Only English View !]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

thank you , I found the solution I was looking for .
to solve the Issue , I did some steps :

> In order to show the date picker in local language, you need to make
> use of flutter_localizations plugin and specify localizationDelegates
> and supportedLocales inside MaterialApp in your main code

1.Add flutter_localizations plugin in pubspec.yaml and run pub get.

```
flutter_localizations:
        sdk: flutter
```

2.Import the plugin in dart file

```
import 'package:flutter_localizations/flutter_localizations.dart';
```

3.Inside MaterialApp, add following

```
  return GetMaterialApp(
       localizationsDelegates: [
         GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate
       ],
       supportedLocales: [
         const Locale('en'),
         const Locale('ar')
       ],
```

4.then implement default datePicker as following

```
 DateTime selectedDate = DateTime.now();

  Future<void> _selectDate(BuildContext context) async {
    final DateTime picked = await showDatePicker(
        context: context,
        initialDate: selectedDate,
        firstDate: DateTime(2000, 1),
        lastDate: DateTime(2100),
        builder: (BuildContext context, Widget child) {
          return Theme(
            data: Theme.of(context).copyWith(
                colorScheme: ColorScheme.light(primary: primaryColor)),
            child: child,
          );
        });

    if (picked != null && picked != selectedDate) {
      selectedDate = picked;
    }
  }
```

5.finally call the previous method into your date TextField as following

```
Expanded(
       child: CustomTextField(
         hint: "date".tr,
         onPress: () => _selectDate(context),
        ),
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you be more specific on which package you are using?. For example flutter_datetime_picker have parameter locale, where you can pass LocalType.ar

```
  static Future<DateTime?> showPicker(
BuildContext context, {
bool showTitleActions: true,
DateChangedCallback? onChanged,
DateChangedCallback? onConfirm,
DateCancelledCallback? onCancel,
locale: LocaleType.en,
BasePickerModel? pickerModel,
DatePickerTheme? theme,
```

Edited per Nader clarification, you can pass locale:Locale("ar") to the internal date_picker

```
  const Locale(
this._languageCode, [
this._countryCode, ])
```

Comment: I'm not using an external package , it's a showDatePicker built in method into flutter . I can only show an english view through this constructor =>  locale: Locale("en").

Comment: Ok, so in the internal showDatePicker(), there is also a param locale in the native one, you can pass locale: Locale("ar")

Comment: I already did, and it shows an error says "No MaterialLocalizations found." . however I'm using Getx state managment and GetMaterialApp as a root of the app .

Comment: Can you be more specific next time asking question 
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

So can you explain the steps you make, the code where you init you local in the main.dart

Have you added Arabic as supported locale?

Comment: sorry , I  provided my question with more details

Answer (score 0):

##### use this it worked for me -

> add flutter_localizations to pub.yaml

> add this two line to main material app widget

```
localizationsDelegates[GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate],
supportedLocales: [const Locale('en'), const Locale('ar')],
```

for me my main looklike -

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return GetMaterialApp(
    localizationsDelegates: [GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate],
    supportedLocales: [const Locale('en'), const Locale('ar')],
    debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    initialRoute: get_initial_route(),
    getPages: app_routes());
}
}
```

> place it in your code in any child widget from this material -

```
IconButton(
    onPressed: () async {
      final DateTime? pickedDate = await showDatePicker(
          context: context,
          initialDate: DateTime(1999),
          firstDate: DateTime(1960),
          lastDate: DateTime(2025),
          locale: Locale('ar'));
    },
    icon: Icon(
      Icons.date_range,
      color: Colors.blue,
    ),
  ),
```

and we are done every thing should be ok